# How to make a measure that calculates Realised Profit or Loss only Stocks that are sold

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I've learnt a lot, all thanks to excellent help from Sam Nseir!

Here is the sample Data -

```
Tradebook
```

| Symbol | Trade Date | Trade Type | Quantity | Price | Trade ID | Order ID | Order Execution Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OLECTRA | 2023-07-11 | buy | 1 | 1327.95 | 43120027 | 1200000017979354 | 2023-07-11T12:39:23 |
| POLYCAB | 2023-07-24 | buy | 1 | 4711.9 | 41759478 | 1200000010492734 | 2023-07-24T10:34:08 |
| ITC | 2023-07-24 | buy | 4 | 491.45 | 22103976 | 1100000010768716 | 2023-07-24T10:34:21 |
| OLECTRA | 2023-07-25 | sell | 1 | 1122.6 | 41335416 | 1200000007499111 | 2023-07-25T10:07:38 |
| ITC | 2023-07-25 | sell | 2 | 459.5 | 21517739 | 1100000008006544 | 2023-07-25T10:08:47 |
| EQUITASBNK | 2023-08-02 | buy | 2 | 89.9 | 27895708 | 1100000039499407 | 2023-08-02T15:22:17 |

***Realised P&L -***
I have the above table I want to calculate the realised Profit or Loss incurred in the above transactions.
For eg. I only sell Olectra and ITC at a loss so that should only show in the Realised P&L.

***Unrealised P&L***
I want to calculate the unrealised profit and loss. That is sold stocks should stay out of those calculations.

***Measure that Calculates the Contribution of each stock in P&L*** - I want to create a treemap that'll show the Contribution of the P&L of each stock irrespective of whether it is bought or sold.

I know I can calculate it with a calculated column with the `P&L= Tradebook[Quantity]*Tradebook[Price]`. But if there are better ways without making a calculated column?

For Calculating Profit or Loss - Let's assume the current price as the latest price for that Stock with respect to Trade Date.